# the id of cart shows null in controller but i m sure i m sending it NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I m sending the id of the product from this view (I m using express and mongoose db)

```
    <form action="/cart" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= product._id %>" />
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
```

I m sure it is not null here

then I have this middleware to receive it

```
router.post("/cart", shopController.postCart);
```

and here is the function post Cart

```
exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.params.id;
  console.log("id returned from the params : " + prodId);
  Product.findById(prodId)
    .then((product) => {
      console.log(product);
      return req.user.addToCart(product);
    })
```

When I first receive it in the postcard function I made a log and it gives me the log console

```
id returned from the params: undefined
null
```

I tried wrapping the id with ObjectId of mongoose then it shows me this message

```
exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.params.id;
  console.log("id returned from the params : " + ObjectId(prodId));
  Product.findById(ObjectId(prodId))
    .then((product) => {
      console.log(product);
      return req.user.addToCart(product);
    })
```

error :

```
id returned from the params : 62c9a1ca3b17ea86134d12fc
null
```

product:
in database :

```
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "62c87c728594df06fd459521"  },  "title": ",gh,",  "price": 44,  "description": "nfggfngh ",  "imageUrl": "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/stack-of-books-picture-id157482029?s=612x612",  "userId": {    "$oid": "62c71d0ab0312958a8082d6f"  },  "__v": 0}
```

Comment: no, you are not sending an parameter

Comment: f me bro i send it in the body and I was trying to receive it in the head ,thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `const prodId = req.params.id;` with `const prodId = req.body.id;` and write

```js
router.post("/cart", express.urlencoded({extended: false}), shopController.postCart);
```

The [`express.urlcoded`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) middleware is needed to fill the `req.body`.